# Windows 10 claims a driver is not signed. Which one is meant?

Tags: malware, windows, drivers

Windows 10 pops regularly a warning about the installation of the unsigned driver and asks whether it really should install it. 
Since I didn't install any new hardware immediately before I can't find out which driver the warning is related to.

I can see that the issuer of the popup is the process rundll (what else) but don't see which driver is meant. How can I find the driver and/or hardware causing this warning for further investigation?

Comment: Simple question: are you using a Dell computer/laptop? And is that warning new? Like, it started happening in the last 2-3 weeks or so?

Comment: Absolutely correct. Dell Precision with Windows 10 and 2-3 weeks ago the first occurence. No new/unrecognized devices in Device Manager and no indications which driver is meant